# Being throttled by Azure with retry policy of 10 minutes

Tags: c#, web-services, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a simple console application that upload a message to a queue in Azure Service Bus, later I download the message and it throws this error: The request was terminated because the entity is being throttled. Error code : 50005. Please wait 00:00:10 seconds and try again. b1e7eb0b-5292-4b0c-8546-2877bfe961b8_G12.

I don't understand why this happens if I have a retry policy of 5 retries in a 10 minutes period. Here is the code. Could you please tell me why is this happenning?

```
 public WebService UpAndDownloadMessage()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServiceBus.NameSpace"].ConnectionString;
        var queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBus.QueueName"];

        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
        var key = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var messageToUpload = new BrokeredMessage("This is a test message! " + key.ToString());

        client.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), 5);

        WebService service = new WebService()
        {
            Name = "AzureServiceBus",
            InitDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        };

        try
        {
            // Send the message
            client.Send(messageToUpload);

            // Get and delete the message
            client.OnMessage(message =>
             {
                 String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>());
                 String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId);
             });

            service.EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            service.Status = Status.Operational;
            service.ErrorMessage = "Operational";
            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            service.EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            service.Status = Status.Down;
            service.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            service.ErrorMessage = service.ErrorMessage.Replace("\"", "");
            service.ErrorMessage = service.ErrorMessage.Replace("\'", "");

            return service;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already kind of resolved that thing. The messaged just stop appear when I added a line with client.close(). hope this be useful to someone else.